# Kqueue on regular files

Tags: c, macos, sockets, operating-system, kqueue

Is kqueue (on OS X) useful for reading/writing regular files?  I know that epoll is *not* useful for regular files on Linux, so I'm wondering if the same is true for kqueue.

EDIT: I don't mean reading/writing files, obviously read() and write() are for that.  I meant, "is kqueue actually useful for detecting when a file is readable/writable?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, kqueue can be used to watch files for readability. From the man page:

```
 EVFILT_READ      Takes a file descriptor as the identifier, and returns
                  whenever there is data available to read.  The behavior
                  of the filter is slightly different depending on the
                  descriptor type.

 [...]

                  Vnodes
                      Returns when the file pointer is not at the end of
                      file.  data contains the offset from current posi-
                      tion to end of file, and may be negative.
```

("vnodes", in this context, are regular files.)

As regular files are always writable, it makes no sense to apply `EVFILT_WRITE` to them.

Comment: How do you know regular files are always writable?

Comment: Files don't become temporarily nonwritable (from being "full") in the same sort of way that sockets, pipes, and whatnot can.

Comment: @duskwuff no, but they definitely block.  They can cause application lag/hang ups.  The whole point of using these mechanisms is signal an event on these resources and when accessing these resources will not block in relation to these events.  "full" concept is irrelevant.

Comment: @Rahly buffered file reads only block in the sense that the data may need to be fetched from disk. As the kqueue docs suggest, the data does not need to be in memory - just available on disk - for a descriptor to be considered ready to read. buffered file writes only block if the system lacks the memory to copy the write buffer into a kernel buffer all at once. File write buffering is why fsync exists. File I/O is buffered unless O_DIRECT is applied to the descriptor.

Answer (score 2):

Kernel Queues are mechanisms which ["allow you to intercept kernel-level events to receive notifications about changes to sockets, processes, the file system and other aspects of the system."](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/SystemTechnology/SystemTechnology.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001067-CH207-SW30)

I've used them in the past to [detect when when actions happen on a file](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/KernelQueues/KernelQueues.html) (or within a hot folder).  I don't believe they can be used for "reading" and "writing" files, though.  You can use MacOS native functions or regular UN*X style "`fopen`", "`fwrite`" and "`fread`" calls for this too, if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

you can technically use it to poll for read availability.

but read availability just means there's data available on the disk, not that the data is already buffered and ready to be served. So a subsequent read may still block.

writes on files are normally non-blocking as long as there is enough memory. Writes are essentially a memcpy into another buffer inside the kernel, and that buffer will eventually be committed to the disk.

this is also why poll always returns ready for regular files.

On Linux and the BSDs O_DIRECT and O_SYNC change this behavior, on OS X I believe there is a fcntl that behaves similarly.  It's almost always a bad idea to use these though.